# On weak convergence of probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

Given probability density function(pdf) $f_n,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, if there exists some constanct $c>0$ such that $f_n \to c\cdot g$ pointwise, do we necessarily have $c=1$?

Applying Fatou's lemma immediately gives that $c\leq 1$, but is it possible that $c<1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)={\bf 1}_{[-1/2,0]\cup[n,n+1/2]}(x)$ and $g(x)=2\cdot{\bf 1}_{[-1/2,0]}(x)$, then $c=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be any pdf, and $f_n= {1\over2}(g+n(n+1) 1_{[{1 \over n+1},{1 \over n}]})$. Then $f_n(x) = {1 \over 2} g(x)$ after a finite number of $n$.

Comment: Technically, OP said $c>0$.

Comment: Oops, missed that!